# Prove: If $\Gamma$ is a collection of subspaces that is totally ordered by set inclusions, then the union of all members of $\Gamma$ is a subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra

I have been mulling this problem over in my mind for the last couple days and I am stuck. There must be some basic principal I am missing. Closure with respect to scalar multiplication is obvious. However I just don't see the addition unless I can directly say $\Gamma$ is a subspace its self. (If this is the case can someone please provide me with some kind of justification.) Taking the assumption it is a subspace my proof is as follows.

Consider $\Gamma$ a collection of subspaces that is totally ordered by set inclusion that is $\Gamma = \{A_i: i \in \Lambda\}$. Then $\Gamma$ is also a subspace. Let $\alpha, \beta \in \Phi$ and $x,y\in \Gamma$ be arbitrary. $\Gamma$ a subspace implies that $\alpha x + \beta y \in \Gamma$. Hence $\alpha x + \beta y \in \cup A_i$ and the union of all members of $\Gamma$ is a subspace.

Answer (score 1):

Your notation doesn't really make sense. The set $\Gamma$ is a set of subspaces, not a subspace itself. Let's show that $\bigcup\Gamma$ is closed under addition. Suppose $x,y\in\bigcup\Gamma$. Then there exists $A,B\in\Gamma$ such that $x\in A$ and $y\in B$. Since $\Gamma$ is totally ordered by inclusion, either $A\subseteq B$ or $B\subseteq A$. In the first case, this implies $x\in B$, so $x+y\in B\subseteq\bigcup\Gamma$, and in the second case this implies $y\in A$ so $x+y\in A\subseteq\bigcup\Gamma$.

The same idea, but worded differently, would be to note that if $A,B\in\Gamma$ then $A\cup B$ is equal to either $A$ or $B$, and hence is closed under addition. If $x,y\in\bigcup\Gamma$ then there exists $A,B\in\Gamma$ such that $x,y\in A\cup B$.

Comment: Thank you soooooo much. I have not worked with totally ordered sets before so its properties were not clear to me.